# parsing an xml response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an XML Response as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t0>
   <t9>0</t9>
   <t1>
      <t15>LUI</t15>
      <t3>1353.50</t3>
      <t6>25</t6>
      <t4>12.40</t4>
      <t5>0.92</t5>
      <t7>1342.50</t7>
      <t8>1368.90</t8>
        </t1>

<t1>
      <t15>LUI</t15>
      <t3>1233.50</t3>
      <t6>25</t6>
      <t4>12.40</t4>
      <t5>0.92</t5>
      <t7>1342.50</t7>
      <t8>1368.90</t8>
        </t1>

</t0>
```

From the XML response I want to read only the first root t1 tag and ignore the second t1 tag

I Culd able to do this with the help of Jquery

```
$(data).find("t1").each(function () {

    return false; 
});
```

i need to  achieve this without returning  false at the end .

taht is something like `$(data).find("t1")[0]`

Is that possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've many ways to achieve it, one way is to use **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)**:

```
var firstT1 = $(data).find("t1").first();
```

Comment: I tried this way as you suggested  $(data).find("t1").first() {               var symbol = $(this).find("t2").text();  } , but it didn't worked .

Comment: You need to use: `var symbol = firstT1.find("t2").text();` or `var symbol = $(data).find("t1").first().find("t2").text();`